# I want to handle the data sets which have patterned name

Tags: r

For example, SAS code is like this ;

(I can't write my whole SAS code so it may be strange)

```
%do a=1 to 100;
data result_&a;
set example;
run;
%end;
```

As you know, the data sets are named like this;

result_1, result_2, ..., result_100

And then, I can handle in SAS like this;

```
data result_&a;
set result_&a;
run;
```

My problem is I don't know how to handle the data sets named like result_&a in R.

Comment: You can use a combination of `(m)get` and `paste0` : `mget(paste0('result_',1:5))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @etienne. My question is how can I call the data sets named like that. SAS can call data sets using 'result_&a' but when I use R I don't have idea.

Comment: Thanks @lukeA. However your comment is working in SAS not in R. I want to know how can I use 'result_&a' in R.

Comment: @suhyun: if the data sets are created, `get` or `mget` allow you to use them. To create them you can look at `assign`. `paste0` allows you to create multiple names